# MySQLi + PHP - Getting a field's result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, mysqli

I'm quite new to PHP, and I'm not sure how I should go about doing the following. I'm not even quite sure how I can describe what I'm trying to accomplish, so here is an example of the Node.JS way of doing what I'm trying to do:

Node.JS:

```
connection.query("blah blah", function (err, result)) {
  var final = result[0].columnName
}
```

Setting that var `final` is what I'm trying to do in PHP. I want to be able to get the value of the field of row `0` and column `columnName`.

Since I don't know how to explain this without the example in Node.JS, I have no clue how I can Google it or search Stack Overflow for it. If anyone knows how I can do this in PHP, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform the query, fetch a row of results, and access the column from that.

```
$conn = new mysqli("servername", "username", "password", "databasename");
$result = $conn->query("blah blah");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$final = $row['columnName'];
```